# QQuickItem::clipRect clips QSGNode in QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I made a QML component based on `QQuickItem`. I redefined the `QQuickItem::clipRect()` method in it in order to clip nested components (childrens) along a certain border, which is smaller than the size of the component itself. In the QQuickItem::updatePaintNode() method I paint a custom `QSGNode` based on `QSGGeometryNode/QSGGeometry/QSGFlatColorMaterial`. The problem is that when I need the geometry in `QQuickItem::clipRect()` and `clip: true` on the component, the rendered `QSGNode` is clipped along the boundary specified in `QQuickItem::clipRect()`.

What needs to be done to get the `QSGNode` to be drawn outside of `QQuickItem::clipRect()`?